# Parsing Coordinate data in php and avoid fatal memory error

Tags: php, string, memory-leaks, coordinates, explode

I have coordinates for a given marker as a string that I need to transform into a 2-dimensional array the first index being an array of x values and the second of y.

For each marker the string of coordinates looks something like this:

```
$strCoordinatesMarker1 = "0,0,12:0,43,4";
```

The output of the above example for just a single marker would be

```
$coordinatesMarker 1 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 12
        )
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 43
            [2] => 4
        )
)
```

And the file outputs an array of all the markers and each coordinate data

So far my code has been working fine with this

```
// Looping through the query of markers from the DB 
// $strCoordinates is returned for each:

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $xyArray = explode(':', $strCoordinates);
    $coordinates = array(explode(',', $xyArray[0]), explode(',', $xyArray[1]));

    $completeCoordinates[] = array('coordinates' => $coordinates);
}
```

This served its purpose with small datasets, I recently got one that was 300 markers and each marker had upwards of 3500 coordinates.

Trying my code on this dataset I got the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 72 bytes)
```

So my question is: **Would there be a more efficient way to do this parsing in php?** I'm fairly new to php programming and wonder if using explode in this way is eating up lots of memory. I want to make sure my code works as best it can before potentially increasing the memory which I don't really want to do for this one off large dataset.

Comment: the better question to ask is: do you actually need to keep all 3500 coordinates in memory at the same time? if no, just discard data you don't need anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use a file stream wrapper

The advantage here is your memory footprint is tiny while using the file streams. The trade off is it may be a bit slower or take longer overall.

Its better (obviously) if your data is already in a file, but you can use a string. In that case you'll have to create a temp file which probably adds a bit of overhead.  The `php://temp` will keep apx 2M of data in memory (if I remember correctly),like `php://memory`, but unlike that stream resource it will start to offload data that is larger then that to a temp file.

```
//If you have a string you can use a temp file
//I mainly did this as it's easier for me to test it
$f = fopen('php://temp', 'w+'); //open in write + read
fwrite($f, "0,0,12:0,43,4");  //write the string to tmp 
rewind($f); //rewind the file to the start, reset the file pointer

//if you have a file you can do this instead of the above 
//$f = fopen('yourfile.txt', 'r');
$result = [];
$buffer = '';
$sub = [];

while(!feof($f)){   
    $c = fgetc($f);
    if(':' == $c || false === $c){
        if(!empty($buffer)){
            $sub[] = $buffer;
            $buffer = '';
        }
        if(!empty($sub)){
            $result[] = $sub;
            $sub = [];
        }
    }elseif(',' == $c){
            $sub[] = $buffer;
            $buffer = '';
    }else{
            $buffer .= $c;
    } 
}

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 12
        )   
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 43
            [2] => 4
        )
)
```

I should add that this should handle variable length parts, it should be fine so long as you only have `0-9`, `:` and `,` in there.  If you have other stuff, that will windup in the output array `in the }else{`.  That said, it's pretty easy to just add another condition to handle that. For example I tested this string `0,0,12:0,43,4::0,2,6,454654,3` which gave me the following output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 12
        )  
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 43
            [2] => 4
        )    
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 454654
            [4] => 3
        )    
)
```

Unfortunately none of the online sandboxes I know of allow you to use the file functions, for security reasons.  I did test it locally though.

In any case it's not something I can really benchmark, these are just a few quick ideas I had for other ways to parse the data.

**One last thought**

It looks like you store this in the DB. If that is the case you have to get it from somewhere to put it in the DataBase:

> I recently got one that was 300 markers ..

This implies that you recently got some "new" data.  So you could offload the parsing of this to where you add that to the DB. Then store it in a better format so you don't have to parse it later, such as JSON or a serialized array etc.  Then when you have the overhead of everything else you are doing here, you can avoid this by preloading it formatted already.  Also I don't know what your source is it could be a URL (which also can be used as a file) or it could be something you download etc.

This is actually a very powerful way of parsing data, I've done things up in the Gb range.  It takes a bit longer to process, but the only memory use is to keep the resource open and read 1 single character from that resource (As a stream).

Cheers.

Comment: Three elements was used for example, the length can differ greatly, where my code breaks is when there is 3500

Comment: Well you did put this `So my question is: Would there be a more efficient way to do this parsing in php?`  You should provide a better example that illustrates those differences.  For example it may be possible to use `preg_match_all`